# Using JFrame.pack() in a loop

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread, pack

I would like progressively modify a java JFrame design structure, as in the this simple example. In a loop I'am increasing de preferredWidth of a JPanel and using the method pack(). But apparently the pack method is ignored. If I put the pack out of the loop, using it only one time, it's work. Anyone know the reason and a possible solution?

```
public class Calculadora extends JFrame {

private JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
private boolean flag;

public Calculadora() {
    JPanel pnlPrincipal = new JPanel();
    pnlPrincipal.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    pnlPrincipal.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    JButton btnAnexo = new JButton("Anexo");
    btnAnexo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (flag) {
                closeAnexo();
                flag = false;
            } else {
                openAnexo();
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    });
    pnlPrincipal.add(btnAnexo);
    this.pnl.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.pnl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 300));
    this.add(pnl, BorderLayout.EAST);
    this.add(pnlPrincipal, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}

private void openAnexo() {
    new Thread () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = pnl.getWidth(); i <= 200; i++) {
                pnl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(i, 300));
                pack();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

private void closeAnexo() {
    new Thread () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = pnl.getWidth(); i >= 0; i--) {
                pnl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(i, 300));
                pack();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Calculadora();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
private void openAnexo() {
    new Thread () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = pnl.getWidth(); i <= 200; i++) {
                pnl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(i, 300));
                pack();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Swing components must be created/updated in the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Having said this your thread is blocking the EDT causing the GUI becomes unresponsive. You should synchronize this new thread with the EDT by using [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29). Or even better you can do repetitive tasks using a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) which is a convenience class to handle all this concurrency stuff.

For example:

```
private void openAnexo() {
    javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(200, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int width = pnl.getWidth();
            if(width > 200) {
                ((javax.swing.Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
            } else {
                pnl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width + 1, 300));
                Calculadora.this.pack();
            }

        }
    });
    timer.setRepeats(true);
    timer.setDelay(200);
    timer.start();
}
```

Take a look to [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) tutorial for a better explanation.

I don't know what are you trying to achieve with this, but be aware of this: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) (Yes we should).

Answer (score 0):

You should use appropriate [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) in this case:

```
JPanel pnlPrincipal = new JPanel();
pnlPrincipal.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

// or

JPanel pnlPrincipal = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

Comment: The problem persists. Because I add the second JPanel in the JFrame and not in this JPanel. So the layout makes no difference.